# How can I preview my image before upload?

Tags: javascript, html

so I have created a form that previews the image before uploading, below is how I created it

```
<div class="w-full mt-1 ml-2">
    <div class="w-full flex left_flex gap-3">
        <div class="overflow-hidden w-10 h-10 shrink-0 rounded-full center_flex bg-gray-100 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-slate-200">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined text-slate-300" id="dummy_img">account_circle</span>
            <img src="" alt="" class="w-full h-full object-cover hidden" id="display_photo">
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="choose_photo" class="p-1 shrink-0 hover:bg-green2 hover:text-blue-text rounded ring-1 text-sm ring-slate-300 hover:ring-green2">Choose photo</button>
        <span class="text-sm max-w-[20rem] Oneline" id="display_filename"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="user__photo" id="user__photo" class="hidden" onchange="user__photo(event)">
</div>
```

and my user__photo function is:

```
    const user__photo = (event) => {
         document.getElementById('dummy_img').classList.add('hidden');

         var display = document.getElementById('display_photo');
         display.classList.remove('hidden')

         display.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
         display.onload = function() {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(display.src)
         }
    }
```

but the console says user__photo is not a function...

can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Wy don't you go the classic way `function user_photo(e)`?

Comment: it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Change `const user__photo = (event) => {` to `function user__photo (event) {`

It's working here: https://jsbin.com/mamodafibe/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function user__photo (event) {
      console.log('file changed')
      console.log(event)
    }
```

```html
<div class="w-full mt-1 ml-2">
    <div class="w-full flex left_flex gap-3">
        <div class="overflow-hidden w-10 h-10 shrink-0 rounded-full center_flex bg-gray-100 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-slate-200">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined text-slate-300" id="dummy_img">account_circle</span>
            <img src="" alt="" class="w-full h-full object-cover hidden" id="display_photo">
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="choose_photo" class="p-1 shrink-0 hover:bg-green2 hover:text-blue-text rounded ring-1 text-sm ring-slate-300 hover:ring-green2">Choose photo</button>
        <span class="text-sm max-w-[20rem] Oneline" id="display_filename"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="user__photo" id="user__photo" class="hidden" onchange="user__photo(event)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const user__photo = (event) => {
      alert('file changed')
    }
```

```html
<div class="w-full mt-1 ml-2">
    <div class="w-full flex left_flex gap-3">
        <div class="overflow-hidden w-10 h-10 shrink-0 rounded-full center_flex bg-gray-100 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-slate-200">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined text-slate-300" id="dummy_img">account_circle</span>
            <img src="" alt="" class="w-full h-full object-cover hidden" id="display_photo">
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="choose_photo" class="p-1 shrink-0 hover:bg-green2 hover:text-blue-text rounded ring-1 text-sm ring-slate-300 hover:ring-green2">Choose photo</button>
        <span class="text-sm max-w-[20rem] Oneline" id="display_filename"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="user__photo" id="user__photo" class="hidden" onchange="user__photo(event)">
</div>
```